# Getting error while SSH to VM of Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssh, azure-aks

Below is my version of azure-cli

```
az --version
```

> azure-cli                         2.0.75 *
>
> command-modules-nspkg              2.0.3
>      core                              2.0.75 *
>      nspkg                              3.0.4
>      telemetry                          1.0.4
>
> Python location '/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.75/libexec/bin/python'
>      Extensions directory '/Users/alexchun/.azure/cliextensions'
>
> Python (Darwin) 3.7.4 (default, Oct 12 2019, 18:55:28) 
>      [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)]
>
> Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal

I tried to follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) but there is no *vmss* found. Then I tried to run `az aks nodepool list --resource-group myResourceGroup --cluster-name myAKSCluster` to double check whether I could [find vmss information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools) or not (as I enabled vmss when creating AKS) but with it required me to install aks-preview.

When I wanted to install `az extension add --name aks-preview` but with below error:

> Unable to get extension index.
>   Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aka.ms',   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /azure-cli-extension-index-v1 (Caused by  SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert  internal error')])")))

Thus, I also tried [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/vmaccess) to SSH Azure VM directly but failed. (I tried to SSH with manual created Ubuntu VM before successfully)

---

Supplement:
I recreated new AKS with VMSS (enable port 22) but still could not SSH to it:
[image]

Faced error:

> ssh: connect to host 5x.1xx.1xx.2xx port 22: Operation timed out

There is no External-IP and I SSH with Internal-IP but failed:
[image]

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your issue, the steps in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) is no problem. When you check the VMSS with the command here:

```
CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP=$(az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv)
SCALE_SET_NAME=$(az vmss list --resource-group $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP --query [0].name -o tsv)
```

You need to use your own resource group which the AKS cluster in. And then, if there is no information about the VMSS, it means you do not enable the VMSS when you create the AKS cluster. At this time, you just need to SSH the VMs using the means in that link.

Finally, maybe you can upgrade the Azure CLI to the newest version, then try to install the extension again.

Comment: Hi Charles, sorry that I was in vacation before. I still could not SSH to VMSS. I checked IP through vmss's "Public IP address" under Overview. Do you know what's wrong for me that cannot ssh to vmss? thanks.

Comment: @DaiKeung There is something you misunderstand. The VMSS of the AKS, it does not have the public IP and I also do not recommend you use the public IP to SSH into it because of the security. Just follow the steps in the link.

Comment: May you tell me what command I should get the IP? As the link just ask me to refer another link for commands to get IP, but I tried with fail.

Comment: @DaiKeung Execute the command `kubectl get nodes -o wide` and you can get all the nodes and their IPs.

Comment: there is no External-IP and I SSH with Internal-IP but failed. You may refer to the picture that I attached. What else should I do? thanks.

Comment: @DaiKeung I think you do not understand the link. There are no public IPs for the VMSS of the AKS cluster. You need to use the pod as a jump box and SSH the nodes from the pods. Do you understand?

Comment: @DaiKeung That's great!